# error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('six>=1.9')

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, python, pip

I'm compiling a yocto build using `bitbake` and upon doing so, I'm seeing the following errors in the log file

```
Searching for six>=1.9
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/six/

Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/six/: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name 
resolution -- Some packages may not be found!

Couldn't find index page for 'six' (maybe misspelled?)

Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)

Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/

Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution -- Some packages may not be found!

No local packages or working download links found for six>=1.9
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('six>=1.9')

ERROR: python setup.py install execution failed.
```

When I try to install `six`, I see the following issues

```
$pip install six
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

With `pip3`

```
$pip3 install six
Collecting six

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connection.py", line 140, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 67, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 732, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Linux version: `x86 4.15.0-139-generic #143~16.04.1-Ubuntu`

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details, nor if you've made changes to the default version of `python` (or `python3`) which can create issues... Compare you version of python with what your release should have (we can't do that as you've not provided enough detail for us to help you).

Comment: From your first error log: "Temporary failure in name resolution" - looks like you have an internet connection-related problem. Either you're not connected to the outer world, or your machine does not have a proper DNS server selected (or selected at all), resulting with you unable to find the correct server to download from.

Comment: my bad. just updated the OS version @guiverc

Comment: Just a reminder 16.04 reaches end of standard support on April 22 2021. You may want to think about upgrading to 18.04 or 20.04. End of Stand Support means no more support or updates. You may not ask questions here either as 16.04 will be off topic. If you sign up for ESM you can still get security patches but that is all.

Comment: @David noted...